# update and delete statements don´t run from php

Tags: php, oracle

I hope you can help me, I'm kinda new at php and I'm having some troubles with some statements that don't run from php,I have some functions that perform some update or delete statements in my DB but I'm having problems with these 2 functions that don't seem to run, here's my code:

```
public function delete_roles($ubuser9) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM WFROLES1 WHERE WFUSRCOD=:ubuser9_bv";
    $stid = oci_parse($this->conn, $query);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':ubuser9_bv', $ubuser9);
    oci_execute($stid);
    return $stid;
}


public function delete_sol_suc($ubuser10) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM WFUSERS1 WHERE WFUSRCOD=:ubuser10_bv";
    $stid = oci_parse($this->conn, $query);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':ubuser10_bv', $ubuser10);
    oci_execute($stid);
    return $stid;
}
```

I have similar functions that delete or update fields in other tables and run without problems, for example these one :

```
    public function delete_perfiles($ubuser4) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM PRFU00 WHERE UBUSER=:ubuser4_bv";
    $stid = oci_parse($this->conn, $query);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':ubuser4_bv', $ubuser4);
    oci_execute($stid);
    return $stid;
}
```

I call the functions in another php file in the following way:

```
   require_once("Includes/db.php");
   VacasDB::getInstance()->update_sucydatos($_SESSION['ubuser']);
   VacasDB::getInstance()->update_cajytes($_SESSION['ubuser']);
   VacasDB::getInstance()->update_espatrab($_SESSION['ubuser']);
   VacasDB::getInstance()->delete_perfiles($_SESSION['ubuser']);    
   VacasDB::getInstance()->insert_cesado($_SESSION['ubuser']);
   $stid = VacasDB::getInstance()->get_tipocar($_SESSION['ubuser']);
   while ($row=oci_fetch_array($stid)) 
   {
      $_SESSION['tipo']=$row["SNGU01TIP"];
   }
  if ($_SESSION['tipo']==1 || $_SESSION['tipo']==12 || $_SESSION['tipo']==13           || $_SESSION['tipo']==14 || $_SESSION['tipo']==15 || $_SESSION['tipo']==20)

{
    VacasDB::getInstance()->update_habilitado($_SESSION['ubuser']);
}

  VacasDB::getInstance()->update_jefsupl($_SESSION['ubuser']);
  VacasDB::getInstance()->delete_roles($_SESSION['ubuser']);
  VacasDB::getInstance()->delete_sol_suc($_SESSION['ubuser']);
  VacasDB::getInstance()->update_empleado($_SESSION['dni']);
  VacasDB::getInstance()->update_sueldo($_SESSION['dni']);
  VacasDB::getInstance()->update_activ($_SESSION['dni']);
  .....
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in these 2 functions?

Comment: Do you have permission to delete from the two tables in question?

Comment: Hi Cory, Yes I have permission in both tables, in fact if I run the sentences direct on PLSQL they run without problems.